# Ruby on Rails: Taking all linked model objects from an array of retrieved model objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working with a database that has a lot of linked model objects and I'm wondering, if I have a model object called "User" and users can have "Applications" linked to them, what is the easiest way to get the array of all Applications linked to a given array of Users?

For example, if I had a specific subset of Users:

```
@users = User.find_all_by_favorite_color("Green")
@applications = @users.applications # What is the right call here?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@applications = @users.map(&:applications)
```

Comment: This worked, but I had to say `&:application`, not `&:applications`. I'm not entirely familiar with Ruby syntax... can you elaborate on exactly what this function call, and especially the &, means/does?